# How to set data from an array to another array to improve performance

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm currently developing a sheet that shows results from a set of data based on some filters but the data loads to slowly when getting the results, I've tried to follow the Best Practices from Google Documentacion with no luck, how can I set an array for the data to load faster?

Below is the code commented with what I've already tried

```
function realizarBusqueda() {
  var inicio = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("INICIO");
  var aux_tags = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Aux_Tags");
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Data");
  var data_lc = data.getLastColumn();
  var data_lr = data.getLastRow();
  var searchRange = data.getRange(2,1, data_lr, data_lc);
  var inicio_lc = inicio.getLastColumn();
  inicio.getRange("A8:L1000").clearContent();
  inicio.getRange("A8:L1000").clearFormat();
  var countRows = inicio.getMaxRows();
  inicio.deleteRows(20, (20-countRows)*-1);
  if (inicio.getRange("B4").isBlank()) {
    inicio.getRange("A8:L1000").clearContent();
    inicio.getRange("A8:L1000").clearFormat();
    var countRows = inicio.getMaxRows();
    inicio.deleteRows(20, (20-countRows)*-1);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
  else if ((inicio.getRange("B4").getValue() != "" && 
           inicio.getRange("C4").getValue() === "")) {
    //filtrado 1
    var arrayDatos = searchRange.getValues();
    var inicio_fr = 8;
    //var row = new Array(11);
    for (var j = 2; j <= data_lr; j++) {
      //row[j] = new Array(data_lr);
      if (aux_tags.getRange("P2").getValue() === arrayDatos[j-2][4]) {
        var inicio_fc = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayDatos[j-2].length; i++) {
          //row[j][i] = arrayDatos[j-2][i];
          var row = arrayDatos[j-2][i];
          inicio.getRange(inicio_fr, inicio_fc).setValue(row);
          inicio_fc++;
        }
        inicio_fr++;
      }
      //inicio.getRange("A8").setValues(row);
    }
  }
```

I expect the output to load lots faster, currently what I've tried is commented, the code as-is is working but too slow

Comment: Storing some of the `getValue` return values will help. As will using `setValues` to write the row in batch, rather than individually, e.g `inicio.getRange(inicio_fr, 1, 1, row.length).setValues(arrayDatos[j-2])`. Additional speedup would be gained by just storing these rows to write and then writing everything at once after the loop ends, e.g. `output = []; ... output.push(arrayDatos[j-2]); ... if (output.length) {inicio.getRange(inicio_fr, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to update this subject because I figured out myself, see attached the new code with the use of new 2D arrays

```
    ...
    //filtrado 1
    var arrayDatos = searchRange.getValues();
    var inicio_fr = 8;
    var rows = [];
    var row = [];
    for (var j = 2; j <= data_lr; j++) {
      if (aux_tags.getRange("P2").getValue() === arrayDatos[j-2][4]) {
        var inicio_fc = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayDatos[j-2].length; i++) {
          row.push(arrayDatos[j-2][i]);
          if (i == 11) {
            rows.push(row);
            row = [];
          }
        }        
      }
    }
    inicio.getRange(8, 1, rows.length, rows[0].length).setValues(rows);   
  }
```

Now instead of writing on row at a time, I just write the whole array at once